# Visual Studio 2008 debugging: when I click on the play button, it flashes real quick

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am having a weird issue with VS 2008 when I go to debug my program. When I click on the play button to run the program it flashes real quick and goes back to the VB IDE. No matter how many times I click on the play button it continually flashes and then goes back without displaying my form window or anything.

What type of setting would I need to change in order to correct this issue? I've been through most settings in the "my project" section and i do not see anything that could be causing it to do something like this.

My older vb apps I've made seem to work just fine when I click the play button on them. Only noticed this problem whenever I go and make a new vb app.

**update video of what's going on**
http://tinypic.com/r/2eycaas/7

Comment: Did you place any breakpoints in the code?

Comment: No, no breakpoints but i did just have *msgbox("hi")* on the form start and it doesn't even display that when i try to run it.

Comment: No exceptions? Sounds like the program starts and exits immediately. Where did you place you `msgbox`?

Comment: Could you provide more information on your machine is it 64bit, do you have remote debugging installed, is there anything in the debug window?

Comment: First things first. Does this only happen for *one existing* project? Or do you see the exact same thing if you create a new, blank project? File -> New -> Project, WinForms Application

Comment: @cody: Yes, every single new project made is doing this. This *does not* happen to older projects that I've done; only *new projects*.

Comment: @lain: It's windows xp 64-bit. The debugging works on my other older apps when i load them up just fine... but for any new project it doesn't. There's just one type of setting that i am over looking that seems to be switched on.

Comment: Any more incite from either of you? Or anyone else for that matter?

Comment: I hate this kind of answer but have you tried reinstalling VS?

Comment: @SimonBesner: I used the mainnetice/

Comment: @SimonBesner: I used the maintenance in the setup to repair the installation but that didn't help either.

Comment: @SimonBesner: I went ahead and re-installed it and it **STILL** does the same thing!!!!!!

Comment: If you try and build a new project does it build without error? If so then can you run the newly built exe?

Comment: @matt: It does build an EXE but has the same problem when i go run it from the exe file.

Comment: @StealthRT - That seems to me like more of a problem with the .NET framework then rather than Visual Studio. Try re-installing the .NET framework as I think I am correct in saying that a re-install of VS won't necessarily re-install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
[image: VS 2008]

Changing it to x86 instead of Any CPU worked!!!! :) But question is, why me having an Core i7 Quad doesn't support the program when i choose x64.....

David

Comment: Apparently [AnyCPU Exes are usually more trouble than they're worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this?
"
Did we install some third party Add-ins in your machine? If we disable Add-ins (“Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) and run “devenv.exe /safemode”, do we still have the problem? This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins are causing problems.

We also can try to run devenv /resetsettings (Commonly, it makes sense than re-installation) or devenv /setup in Visual Studio Command Prompt.
"
--http://forums.asp.net/t/1324737.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Just check your output window.
Accessible from `Menu-> Debug-> Windows -> Output.` (Check image:1)

In output window select `Show output from: Build` combobox.  (Check image:2)

This will give you perfect idea what is happening.

Following are the guesses.

- The VBC installer is not installed or corrupted.
- Some addon is registered to run before compiling and is creating problem.
- ....Long list until you tell whats shown in output window.

Also check `Show output from: Debug` in output window and Final check would be Immediate window.

I feel this three would give you hint whats going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the startup form correct? You can see that in project properties.